# Interconnect two AWS Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am having a problem when trying to join two AWS servers together using a domain but I'm not sure if this is even the right approach.

[image]

- Server 1 - Is the domain controller
- Server 2 - the computer I am trying
  to join

I have checked the following things but can't think why I would be getting this error

1. Both AWS instances are in the same availability zone
2. Both AWS instances are in the same VPC
3. Both AWS instances have all traffic open in the security group to each other
4. I have disabled the firewalls completely on both server 1 and 2
5. The network adapter on server 2 is configured in the ipv4 properties for the DNS server to point to server 1

I cant ping the server name but can ping the ip address. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Please check the timezone as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to enable the DNS hostnames and resolution of the VPC

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).